# checking if the name of a node is Fox within a template P

Tags: xml, xslt

In a template name P, i want to check if the name of the current node is Fox. I'm wondering what's the *usual* way that people do to do this kind of checks:

```
<xsl:template name="P">
    <xsl:if test="self::Fox">
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

OR:

```
<xsl:template name="P">
    <xsl:if test="name(.)='Fox'">
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

OR: is there another better solution compared to this 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that many people use `[name()='Fox']` but the recommended way, and the way used by experts, is to use `self::Fox`. The main reason for that is that name() is unreliable when there are namespaces around, and the alternative of testing both namespace-uri() and local-name() is cumbersome and verbose. Also, many XPath engines have ways of searching for an element with a given name that don't involve doing string comparisons on every element. Because evaluation of name()=`Fox` requires looking at the namespace prefix, not the URI, which is an uncommon operation, it's also likely to be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred approach is to use the `self` axis as this will take care of namespaces and is more terse.

Note, however, that if your current node is *not* an element node, the `self` axis will not work as you might expect. For example in

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:if test="self::workdir">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The test will never succeed, even if the current processing instruction has the name `workdir`. The same applies to more common case

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:if test="self::href">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Again, the test for `href` attribute will never work as [the *principle node type* for the `self` axis is element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests). In this case you have to use `name()` or `local-name()`

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:if test="name() = 'href'">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart the fact that there is a typo in the first check:

```
 <xsl:if test="self::Fox"/>
```

You might want also compare against the node name independently from its namespace prefix (if any). In that case you can use `local-name()` in place of `name()`.

About the XPath pattern I can't imagine other ways much simpler. For instance, you can write something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="self::*[name()='test']">
```

But it's going to be ridiculous.

Comment: ok thanks i've edited the question accordingly. i've actually had something similar to your second piece of code in my this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463795/canonical-xpath-problems