# canonical xpath problems?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

If a single dot is converted into **self()::node()** in xpath, [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546839%28v=bts.70%29.aspx)

Then why does this work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="self::node()[name()='QWE']"/>
```

but not this?:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".[name()='QWE']"/>
```

Comment: Use Control-K or the `{}` button in the editor when posting code. This is especially important for XML-y code, since the code simply won't appear at all otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the expression

```
.[name()='QWE']
```

is illegal XPath 1.0 syntax, an abbreviated [step](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Step) may *not* contain a predicate. XPath 2.0 doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: ok so are you saying both statements are allowed in XSL 2.0 ?